# Passing two dimensional array of strings to function?

Tags: c, string, function, multidimensional-array

I am trying to send this array to the function `sortByLength`.

The function prototype is

```
sortByLength(char *words[],int * lengths, const int size);
```

Here is the rest of my code up to where I try to pass it to the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "task2.h"
#define SIZE 3

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int lengths[SIZE] = {3, 4, 6};
    char words[][20] = {"Sun", "Rain", "Cloudy"};

    sortByLength(words[][20],lengths,SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why not sortByLength(words, lengths, SIZE);

Comment: @kiks73 It will not work. Because he declared that as  a 2-D array. But he getting that as pointer to pointers.

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S; Its not array of pointers but pointer to pointer.

Comment: @haccks so 'char words[][20]' is a pointer that points to the pointer that points to the first element "Sun"?

Comment: @MilkyCode; No. `words` is an array.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype

```
sortByLength(char *words[],int * lengths, const int size);
```

is equivalent to

```
sortByLength(char **words,int * lengths, const int size);
```

`words[][20]` will converted to *pointer to array of `20` `char`s* when passed to a function. `char **` and `char (*)[20]` are incompatible types. Change function prototype to

```
sortByLength(char (*words)[20], int *lengths, const int size);
```

Comment: or use `sortByLength(words,lengths,SIZE);` instead of `sortByLength(words[][20] ,lengths,SIZE);`.